# Azure Web Site changes Range header to incorrect values

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure, range, azure-web-app-service

I created empty ASP.NET web application with following page and deploy it to Azure Web Site. And my code receives incorrect Range header on GET requests.
POST requests working correctly.

The simples ASP.NET page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Range.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication10.Range" %>

<%
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Write("Range: " + Request.Headers["Range"]);
    Response.End();
%>
```

I send GET request with Range header and something changes it.
Request:

```
GET http://webapplicationXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/Range.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: webapplicationXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net
Range: bytes=0-1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Length: 0
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=...
Date: Fri, 06 Jun 2014 09:51:56 GMT

Range: bytes=0-262143
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Microsoft already fixed this bug.

Now application gets correct header value.

Comment: Having a similar issue. In my case it seems it is filtering out the Range header entirely. This is a basic Azure Web Site.